# How can I open file with code that triggered build error in Android Studio, on Linux?

Tags: linux, android-studio, android-studio-electric-eel

I am pretty sure that this functionality used to exist but nowadays trying to open relevant file gets only error.

[image]

You can, as workaround, search for a relevant code or manually follow path but that is quite silly.

Android Studio Electric Eel | 2022.1.1 Patch 1

Build #AI-221.6008.13.2211.9514443, built on January 21, 2023

Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS, running Lubuntu

Comment: "OSM%20software" looks suspicious. :-) Are you sure it's the real path and not a weird escaping of a space? Many tools break in most surprising ways when paths contain spaces.

Comment: @oakad Hmm, good hint. Yes, there is a space there. Though Android Studio used to be fine with spaces in the path in this specific context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the past Android Studio supported path with a space but one of version regressed.

As Android Studio bug reports are ignored anyway, I have decided to not report it but rather renamed my folder.

I guess that software in AD 3020 will still tend to fail with files and folders that has spaces in them or use letters like Ó or Ę.